# How to combine two queries to see age?

Tags: sql

I have two queries:

This shows people's birth date:

```
select birthday from sm.People where [disabled] = 0
```

This calculate age based on birth date:

```
DECLARE @dob datetime = '1992-01-09 00:00:00'
SELECT CONVERT(int,ROUND(DATEDIFF(hour,@dob,GETDATE())/8766.0,0)) AS AgeYearsIntRound,
       DATEDIFF(hour,@dob,GETDATE())/8766 AS AgeYearsIntTrunc
```

[image]

I need to combine it to see, how many people is 30 y.o., how many 31 etc.

**Edit**

[image]

Comment: select birthday,  CONVERT(int,ROUND(DATEDIFF(hour,BIRTHDAY,GETDATE())/8766.0,0)) AS AgeYearsIntRound,
       DATEDIFF(hour,BIRTHDAY,GETDATE())/8766 AS AgeYearsIntTrunc                   from sm.People where [disabled] = 0

Comment: @Sergey I did it, but it don't show count of each age

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  CONVERT(int,ROUND(DATEDIFF(hour,birthday,GETDATE())/8766.0,0)) AS  AgeYearsIntRound,
  count(*) CNTT
 FROM sm.People where [disabled] = 0
 GROUP BY CONVERT(int,ROUND(DATEDIFF(hour,birthday,GETDATE())/8766.0,0))
```

Could you please try something like that